# firestore: array empty when i try to get data by date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first time using Firestore. I am not able to get the data from firestore when I add filter by date. I would like to retrieve firestore data save the day before (yesterday). i trying many internet's examples.

i try this:

```
const query = this.fb.collection('your_collection');
query(`your_directory`,
  ref =>  ref.orderBy('reportedAt').startAt(new Date(2020, 7, 20, 0, 0, 0)));
```

and this

```
const query = this.fb.collection('your_collection');
query(`your_directory`,
  ref =>  ref.where('reportedAt','>=', new Date(2020, 7, 20, 0, 0, 0)));
```

but every time I use one of these methods, I do not find the expected results. he return an empty array.

Could someone explain to me how to solve my problem?

**EDIT:**
response example. Array this data
[image]
I would like to retrieve a data array whose reportedAt dates from the last day.
this is reportedAt on firebase UI
[image]
[image]

thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to show a specific example of a document that should be matched by your query.  There's nothing we can do without seeing that your query matches your data in every way.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok

Comment: What do you mean you get back an empty array? In the screenshot you are showing as an array that at least has that element

Comment: What if you subtract one day off the Date you pass to the query?  Does it find anything?

Comment: for the example table, i modified my query to show you what it's content should content. sorry I don't usually post on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

finally my request to work and I still do not understand...

this query don't work

```
const query = this.fb.collection('your_collection');
query(`your_directory`,
ref =>  ref.orderBy('reportedAt').startAt(new Date(2020, 7, 20, 0, 0, 0)));
```

but this query work

```
const query = this.fb.collection('your_collection');
query(`your_directory`,
ref =>  ref.orderBy('reportedAt').startAt(new Date("2020-07-20")));
```

the difference is in the way of instantiating the Date object. But as I told you I do not understand this behavior.